# Control Panel for monitoring program jobs

Tags: issue-tracker

We have several small/large scripts running on schedules for a variety of tasks in our company. Currently, if a script fails we just send out an email describing the issue to the appropriate parties.

Naturally, this leads to a flood of emails that often go ignored.

Is there a program or library that allows for the creation of a 'status panel' where we can keep track of issues easily and more cleanly?

These wouldn't be user-submitted issues; they would be given by the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an Issue Tracker. [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) is very popular, but costs. There are many good free (some FOSS) Issue Trackers, with probably the most venerable being [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/).

Just examine some and choose any which fits your needs and is scriptable. Fortunately, Bugzilla has a REST API, as documented [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API).

[image]

If that doesn’t answer your question, please let me know.

---

In addition, you say that you are scheduling your scripts, and I will guess that you use cron jobs or the Windows scheduler. Why not look into [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)?

Despite the name, it is not just for software builds, and can be used for anything schedulable.

Again, there are many solutions, both paid and free. The most popular free solution is probably [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/). It will schedule your scripts for you, email the appropriate people if they fail and provide you with a dashboard overview like this, plus much more

[image]